# Doctrine entity self reference association with additional information

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have an entity Client and this entity needs to have an association to another Client with information about relationship. This entity is ClientRelationship.
I need to have this asociation in one property, because I want to use symfony form with collection type field.
Problem is that I do not know how to write it to have that association in one Client property.

Now I have in Client two asociation properties, but that is my problem. In form on one side is relationship visible, but on other Client its not.

Client entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientRelationship", mappedBy="leftClient", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $leftRelationships;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientRelationship", mappedBy="rightClient")
 */
private $rightRelationships;
```

ClientRelationship entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 255)
 * @Assert\Length(max = 255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $relationship;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="leftRelationships")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leftClient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $leftClient;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="rightRelationships")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rightClient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $rightClient;
```

EDIT: added forms

ClientType form:

```
$builder->add('leftRelationships', 'bootstrap_collection', array(
            'type' => new ClientRelationshipType(),
            'label' => 'relationships',
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'add_button_text'    => 'add',
            'delete_button_text' => 'remove',
            'options' => array(
                'businessCase' => $options['businessCase'],
                'client' => $options['client'],
            ),
        ));
```

ClientRelationshipType form:

```
$builder->add('rightClient', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'client',
            'class' => 'MyProject\CoreBundle\Entity\Client',
            'property' => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function (ClientRepository $er) use ($options)   {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('c');
                    if ($options['businessCase'] instanceof BusinessCase) {
                        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('c.id', ':clients'));
                        $qb->setParameter(':clients',   $options['businessCase']->getClients()->toArray());
                    }
                    if ($options['client'] instanceof Client) {
                        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('c.id', ':client'));
                        $qb->setParameter(':client', $options['client']);
                    }
                    return $qb;
                },
        ));

    $builder->add('relationship', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'relationship',
        ));
```

Comment: Not sure I understand problem your problem correctly. Is form rendered wrong? If so please add Form source. Or when form is submitted only one side is added to relation? Because I believe you have to write code for that yourself.

Comment: Both sides have added relations. I updated post.

Comment: Form is rendered correctly. Data in form are correct too. I only want modify that to variant, where form.leftRelationships shows relations everytime. Not only from one side of relation.